# Visibility of a variable after changing its location

Tags: java

I have a basic question in Java:

Consider I have

```
public void initialize(My_Class my_context)  {
    super.initialize(my_Context);
  }


  public void work(My_Class2 elt) {
    String text = elt.getText();

    My_Class3 var1 = new My_Class3();
    String new_text = var1.my_method(text);
```

I am having a problem because I am calling the work method many times, and each time it instantiates a `My_Class3` object, which takes a lot of time. I would like to move the instantiation in the `initialize` method so that it is performed once.

In order to do that, I tried to move

```
My_Class3 var1 = new My_Class3();
```

into `initialize` and set it as a global variable so that `var1` is found in the different calls of `work`. However, I cannot set it into a static variable. I am guessing this has something to do with the visibility of the `initialize` method, but I cannot change it.

How can I instantiate a `var1` variable of type `My_Class3` in `initialize` and call it in `work?`

Comment: Why not? What error do you get?

Comment: By learning some basic Java... Do you need one My_Class3 per instance of  your class (if so it's an instance var) or just one shared by all (static instance)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
My_Class3 var1;
public void initialize(My_Class my_context)  {
    super.initialize(my_Context);
    var1 = My_Class3();
  }


  public void work(My_Class2 elt) {
    String text = elt.getText();
    String new_text = var1.my_method(text);
}
```